# How to insert one view which "covers" two regions? Prism, WPF, MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I have one view named `FooView` at `ModuleA` and two regions at the `Shell` called `BottomRegion` and `UpperRegion`:

```
<Window x:Class="FooBootstrapper.Shell">    
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <ContentControl  DockPanel.Dock="Top" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.UpperRegion}" Margin="5"/>
        <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.BottomRegion}" Margin="5"  />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

If I paste my `FooView` to the `BottomRegion`, then `FooView` is injected to the `BottomRegion`. And it is normal and logical.

```
protected override void InitializeModule()
{            
   RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.BottomRegion, typeof(FooView));
}
```

However, I would like to inject one whole view `FooView` into two regions: `UpperRegion` and `BottomRegion`. That is I want to have one whole view
inside of `UpperRegion` and `BottomRegion`.

How to insert one view which "covers" two regions(`UpperRegion` and `BottomRegion`)? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Andrew O'Neill](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/andy%20oneill/?ws=usercard-mini) has answered me at [msdn forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2d3178f4-8bb6-4da3-9d65-c4e43d1123a4/how-to-insert-one-view-which-covers-two-regions-prism-wpf-mvvm?forum=wpf). So I post here his answer. I hope it helps to other people:

*It isn't possible.
As you can see from  your code you have two contentcontrols there.
You can set the content of both or either.
You can't say that a control is spread across the contents of this contentcontrol and another.
You could put another  Contentcontrol in a panel (grid)  on top of both and set the contents of that.*

```
<Window x:Class="FooBootstrapper.Shell"> 
<Grid>   
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <ContentControl  DockPanel.Dock="Top" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.UpperRegion}" Margin="5"/>
        <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.BottomRegion}" Margin="5"  />
    </DockPanel>

 <ContentControl ....
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Grid instead of a DockPanel.
Then use Grid.Rowspan or Grid.Columnspan.

Comment: Could you provide some code? How can I use RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(...) method with property Grid.RowSpan?